# Sorting XML based on a child node in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type = "text/xsl" href = "Albums_PS_XSL.xsl"?>
<Albums>
    <Album>
        <Name>Empire Burlesque</Name>
        <Artist>Bob Dylan</Artist>
        <Country>USA</Country>
        <Company>Columbia</Company>
        <Price>10.20</Price>
        <Date>19880610</Date>
    </Album>
    <Album>
        <Name>Hide your heart</Name>
        <Artist>Bonnie Tylor</Artist>
        <Country>UK</Country>
        <Company>CBS Records</Company>
        <Price>9.90</Price>
        <Date>19880509</Date>
    </Album>
    <Album>
        <Name>Greatest Hits</Name>
        <Artist>Dolly Parton</Artist>
        <Country>USA</Country>
        <Company>RCA</Company>
        <Price>9.90</Price>
        <Date>1982</Date>
    </Album>
    <Album>
        <Name>Still got the blues</Name>
        <Artist>Gary More</Artist>
        <Country>UK</Country>
        <Company>Virgin redords</Company>
        <Price>10.20</Price>
        <Date>1990</Date>
    </Album>
    <Album>
        <Name>Eros</Name>
        <Artist>Eros Ramazzotti</Artist>
        <Country>EU</Country>
        <Company>BMG</Company>
        <Price>9.90</Price>
        <Date>1997</Date>
    </Album>
    <Album>
        <Name>25</Name>
        <Artist>Adele</Artist>
        <Country>UK</Country>
        <Company>XL Recordings</Company>
        <Price>9.90</Price>
        <Date>20151120</Date>
    </Album>
    <Album>
        <Name>1000 Forms of Fear</Name>
        <Artist>Sia</Artist>
        <Country>USA</Country>
        <Company>RCA Records</Company>
        <Price>9.90</Price>
        <Date>20140704</Date>
    </Album>
    <Album>
        <Name>Rattle and Hum</Name>
        <Artist>U2</Artist>
        <Country>EU</Country>
        <Company>Island</Company>
        <Price>9.90</Price>
        <Date>19881010</Date>
    </Album>
</Albums>
```

And an XSL file that looks like this, which I wrote:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="Albums">
        <html>
            <body>
            <h2>Albums</h2>         
                <xsl:for-each select="Album">
                    <h2 style="color: green;" ><xsl:value-of select="Country"/></h2>
                        <table border = "1">
                            <tr bgcolor="grey">
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Artist</th>
                                <th>Company</th>
                                <th>Date</th>
                                <th>Price</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="Artist"/></td>                                
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="Company"/></td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="Date"/></td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="Price"/></td>

                            </tr>
                        
                        </table>
                </xsl:for-each>
                
        
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm trying to make it so for each country the album is released in, it will output a table with the albums from that country.
So basically something like (psuedo code):

```
<h2>Country Name</h2>
<table> albums from this country</table>
```

I'm pretty new to this XSL thing, can anyone help?

Comment: You are not trying to sort by country, you are trying to *group* by country. You'll find countless examples of XSLT grouping (the alternative keyword is "Muenchian grouping") here on SO and elsewhere, give them a read.

Comment: Yoni, while asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its compliance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.